# How to get the clicked URL from the BrowserField? 

Tags: blackberry

My application has 2 screens. First screen contains a `BrowserField` instance, which displays a HTML file with lots of link.

When the user clicks on a link displayed on the `BrowserField`, the second screen should come. But now the new page is opening on the `BrowserField`.

How to get the clicked URL from the `BrowserField`?

How to display the new page on the second screen?

Comment: come to below chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java or otherwise put some code snippet here that what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for the class [`BrowserField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html).

Check the method `void setDebugger(`[`BrowserFieldDebugger`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/debug/BrowserFieldDebugger.html)`debugger)`.

Implement the method `public void`[`pageRequested`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/debug/BrowserFieldDebugger.html#pageRequested%28java.lang.String%29)`(String url)`.

---

[`BrowserFieldDebugger`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/debug/BrowserFieldDebugger.html):

> This abstract class allows a developer to debug web content running
>   within a [`BrowserField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) API application.

[`pageRequested`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/debug/BrowserFieldDebugger.html#pageRequested%28java.lang.String%29):

> ```
> This method is invoked for each new page that is requested
>
> Parameters:
>     url - the URL of the newly requested page
> ```